# Getting the identity of the logged in user?

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

The is for a Blazor (server side) application. As I understand it, I have three objects for a logged in user:

- `AuthenticationState` which I can get in my razor page as it's injected. This allows me to make calls to see if claims allow users to take actions or see data.
- `IdentityUser` which is the ASP.NET Identity user which has their email, phone etc. I can get that using the code below.
- User which is my app user object. `User.AspUserId == IdentityUser.Id` so I can read that object once I have the `IdentityUser`.

```
private async Task<IdentityUser?> GetUser()
{
    var userPrincipal = (await authenticationStateTask).User;

    var userid = userPrincipal
                     .FindFirst(u => u.Type.Contains("nameidentifier"))?
                     .Value;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid))
        return await UserDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userid);

    return null;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Are these three objects what I should be using?
2. There's a `AuthenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged` event. Should I set this up and use it to re-read my `IdentityUser` and `User` object and otherwise I can keep those objects without re-reading them per page.
3. If so, where do I store these objects as they're a per session object.
4. Is my `GetUser()` code above the best way to get the `IdentityUser`?

Anything I'm missing in all this?

Comment: Just use the [`UserManager`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/Repositories/AccountRepository.cs#L342) like [this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Server/Controllers/Web/V3/AccountController.cs#L542) or [this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Server/Controllers/Api/V1/AccountController.cs#L73)

Comment: @Pieterjan Thank you, a couple of questions. 1. Is UserManager<Entities.User> automatically added as a service in Blazor server? 2. Where do I get the ClaimsPrincipal from? Is it the one in AuthenticationState? 3. Is IAccountService  automatically added as a service in Blazor server? 4. What/where is the User class some of the calls pass? 5. Are these all tied to the Identity system user that I use to log in a user? TIA.

Comment: When you ask those questions, I really ask myself if you have done some [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=blazor+identity+site%3Astackoverflow.com) ?

Comment: @Luuk Trust me, I have read and read and read. The problem is there are so many answers pointing in different directions. And there are solutions that are not tied to the ASP.NET Identity library/system. You'll note that I did provide a working solution and that came from research.

Comment: `User` is a property on any `Controller`. The `UserManager` becomes available by calling `services.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>()`. You can just clone the repo, open the solution and ctrl+click on anything you want

Comment: As for your comment about not using **Identity**, that should actually be a no-brainer. Just use Identity, it'll make your life much less painfull, especially in the future. It's developed and maintained by Microsoft. They did tons of research in all concepts for sign-in/session persistence/2FA/rbac/password-reset/external-logins. All of this is supported out-of-the-box. I had a job once, where just like you they refused to use Identity (probably because they didn't know it existed). They asked me to implement 2FA, so I had to do tons and tons of research before I could get anything done

Comment: The project I posted incorporates all features and demonstrates that using Identity removes all complexity from your codebase. [Here's a complete dotnet template](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates) that allows you to just select whatever options you want and hit F5 rightaway.

Comment: @Pieterjan My comment was inartfully phrased - I absolutely am using the Identity library. For the very reasons you listed.

Comment: @DavidThielen You can directly use a custom identity user by inheriting instead of separating them in DB:  [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-user-data)

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I think it’s a bad idea to add app specific properties to the Identity DB. By keeping it clean multiple apps can use the same Identity DB allowing the same user login to all apps.

Comment: @Pieterjan UserManager (and SigninManager) are not supported in Blazor server - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer all your questions, you need to consider where you need to consume the current user.

In a component, that's pretty simple.  You can consume the `Task<AuthenticationState>` cascaded parameter.  It's a `Task`,  but will almost always be in the `Completed` state, and return immediately.

If however you need the user context in another service you need to use the registered `AuthenticationStateProvider` service.

Here's a simple User wrapper Service that can be consumed by Services or components.

```cs
public class UserService : IDisposable
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _stateProvider;
    private Task _task = Task.CompletedTask;

    public event EventHandler<UserChangedEventArgs>? UserChanged;

    public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; set; } = new ClaimsPrincipal();

    public UserService(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        _stateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        _stateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += this.OnUserChanged;
        // get the current user. as this is an async method we just assign it to a class variable
        _task = this.GetUserAsync(_stateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }

    public async ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> GetUserAsync()
    {
        // probably complete, but we don't know for sure so always await it
        await _task;
        return User;
    }

    private void OnUserChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        // As this is a fire and forget event we assign the new task to our class task
        // which we can await if we need to
        _task = this.GetChangedUserAsync(task);
    }

    private async Task GetChangedUserAsync(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        // get the user
        await this.GetUserAsync(task);
        // raise our fire and forget event now we've got the new user
        this.UserChanged?.Invoke(this, new UserChangedEventArgs(User));
    }

    private async Task GetUserAsync(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        // Reset the user to a new ClaimsPrincipal which is effectivity no user
        this.User = new ClaimsPrincipal();
        
        // get the state object
        var state = await task;

        // update the user
        if (state is not null)
            this.User = state.User;
    }

    public void Dispose()
         => _stateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged -= this.OnUserChanged;
}

public class UserChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ClaimsPrincipal? User { get; private set; }

    public UserChangedEventArgs(ClaimsPrincipal? user)
        => User = user;
}
```

For reference, here's the code for `CascadingAuthenticationState`:

```cs
@implements IDisposable
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

<CascadingValue TValue="System.Threading.Tasks.Task<AuthenticationState>" Value="@_currentAuthenticationStateTask" ChildContent="@ChildContent" />

@code {
    private Task<AuthenticationState>? _currentAuthenticationStateTask;

    /// <summary>
    /// The content to which the authentication state should be provided.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        AuthenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += OnAuthenticationStateChanged;

        _currentAuthenticationStateTask = AuthenticationStateProvider
            .GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    }

    private void OnAuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> newAuthStateTask)
    {
        _ = InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            _currentAuthenticationStateTask = newAuthStateTask;
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        AuthenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged -= OnAuthenticationStateChanged;
    }
}
```

You see see the original here - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Authorization/src/CascadingAuthenticationState.razor

Comment: And is the `GetUser()` code I have above the best way to then get the IdentityUser?

Comment: Even in a component, would it work well to do the above as a service? Making it a scoped service I can get AuthenticationStateProvider and both DbContext objects, and then read all 3 User objects and cache them, to only re-read on a UserChangedEvent. Good idea? Or if the AuthenticationState is there and available, is it better to use it? Plus, my User object can change even if the logged in user doesn't change because the user can edit their profile.

Comment: "Even in a component, would it work well to do the above as a service?"  It's the difference between half a dozen and six.  A matter of preference.  I've added the code from the `CascadingAuthenticationState` component that is used in `App` so you can see what it does.

Comment: In the service in my answer I've separated out the async `AuthenticationStateChanged` handler and only trigger the `UserChanged` event once I have a user.  If you want to trigger an event when the user updates their profile, you can use the same event.

Comment: It's a matter of "horses for courses" in what you use.  They are all wrappers around the `AuthenticationStateProvider`.  Authentication is a minefield.  I get my head around it, write some code.  Go away and do other stuff for a couple of months.  When I come back, I look blankly at my own code, scratch my head and spend a couple of hours re-acquainting myself with the concepts!

Comment: I’m the same way about css, I can never go back and figure out what I did. I’m going to try the service route - thanks for the guidance.